# Get input from user using a text file

Tags: java, file, input, io

I couldn't get my code work using the try catch when asking for the user's input. Here's the given homework:

> BUS PASSENGER SEAT PROGRAM   Write a program to assign passengers
>     seats in a Bus.  Assume a small bus with seat numbering as follows:
>   1  A B  C D  2  A B  C D  3  A B  C D  4  A B  C D  5  A B  C D  6  A
>   B  C D  7  A B  C D  8  A B  C D   The program should display the seat
>   pattern, with an indicator (e.g. X) marking the seats already
>   assigned.  For example, after seats 1A, 2B and 4C are taken, the
>   display should look like this:   1  X B  C D  2  A X  C D  3  A B  C D
>   4  A B  X D  5  A B  C D  6  A B  C D  7  A B  C D  8  A B  C D
>   After displaying the seats available, the program prompts for the set
>   desired, the user types in a seat, and then the display of available
>   seats is updated.  This continues until all seats are filled or until
>   the user signals that the program should end.  If the user types in a
>   seat that is already assigned, the program should say that the seat is
>   occupied and ask for another choice.   The program outputs the ticket
>   the user booked in a text file and in UI with the following details: 
>        
>     :   The program is also capable of accepting
>   an input text file that contains the details above and determines if
>   the seat number content on the text file is already occupied or not.
>   Likewise, the summary of reserved seats together with the passenger
>   name can be viewed in UI and in another text file. **Sorry for the unorganized placing, I cant seem to put new lines in it.**

Here's my code so far:

```
package busticket;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BusTicket {

    public static void printArray(char[][] Ticket) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Ticket.length; i++) {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + "   " +
                    Ticket[i][0] + " " + Ticket[i][1] + "  " +
                    Ticket[i][2] + " " + Ticket[i][3]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter a;
        String f;

        char Again;
        char[][] Ticket = new char[8][4];


        System.out.println("Hello Sir/Ma'am here is the list of the available seats:");

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            Ticket[i][0] = 'A';
            Ticket[i][1] = 'B';
            Ticket[i][2] = 'C';
            Ticket[i][3] = 'D';
        }

        printArray(Ticket);

        int counter = 0;
        do {

            do {
                System.out.println("Press 1 for Manual input.");
                System.out.println("Press 2 for Text input.");
                int Choice = get.nextInt();

                if (Choice == 1) {
                    get.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
                    String name = get.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Please enter your desired seat. (ex: 1A).");
                    String seat = get.nextLine();

                    int row = seat.charAt(0) - '1';
                    int column = seat.charAt(1) - 'A';

                    if (row < 0 || row > 8 || column < 0 || column > 4) {
                        System.out.println("Wrong input.");
                    } else {
                        if (Ticket[row][column] != 'X') {
                            Ticket[row][column] = 'X';
                            printArray(Ticket);
                            System.out.println("Reserved:" + name + "-" + seat);

                            try {
                                a = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt", true));
                                a.write(String.format(name));
                                a.write("-");
                                a.write(String.format(seat));
                                a.write("\n");
                                a.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            counter++;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("THAT SEAT IS TAKEN!!!");

                        }
                    }
                } else if (Choice == 2) {
                    get.nextLine();
                    try {
                        String str;
                        Scanner g = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
                        while ((str = g.nextLine()) != null) {
                            String[] ar = str.split("-");
                            String name = ar[0];
                            String seat = ar[1];
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                    int row = seat.charAt(0) - '1';
                    int column = seat.charAt(1) - 'A';

                    if (row < 0 || row > 8 || column < 0 || column > 6) {
                        System.out.println("Wrong input.");
                    } else {
                        if (Ticket[row][column] != 'X') {
                            Ticket[row][column] = 'X';
                            printArray(Ticket);
                            System.out.println("Reserved:" + name + "-" + seat);

                            try {
                                a = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt", true));
                                a.write(String.format(name));
                                a.write("-");
                                a.write(String.format(seat));
                                a.write("\n");
                                a.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            counter++;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("THAT SEAT IS TAKEN!!!");

                        }
                    }
                }
                do {
                    System.out.print("\nReserve again? Press Y to Reserve again. Press N to exit and print the receipt.(Y/N): ");
                    Again = get.next().charAt(0);
                    Again = Character.toUpperCase(Again);
                    get.nextLine();
                } while ((Again != 'Y') && (Again != 'N'));
            } while (Again == 'Y');
            if (Again == 'N' || Again == 'n') {
                try {
                    Scanner d = new Scanner(new File("output.txt"));
                    while ((f = d.nextLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println("Reserved:");
                        System.out.println(f);

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } while (counter < 32);
    }
}
```

My problem is with the 2nd choice. 
This part:

```
else if (Choice==2){
         get.nextLine();
            try {
            String str;
            Scanner g = new Scanner (new File("input.txt"));
            while ((str = g.nextLine()) != null){
            String[] ar=str.split("-");
            String name=ar[0];
            String seat=ar[1];
            }
            }catch (Exception e){}
```

How can I let my code read the String name and seat inside the try catch without destroying the logic of my code? All variables inside the try catch can't be read.

Comment: You'll have more success with answers if you narrow your code down to just the relevant lines of code and provide more if asked.

Comment: For this project, just declare the `String name` and `String seat` at the top of the class. For future, you may want to look at encapsulating them in an object and breaking the class down into methods that work with / return the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All variables inside the try catch can't be read

I'm going to guess that you mean "I cannot reference the variables that I declare inside the try-catch from outside the try-catch."

If that's your question, then declare them outside that block, like this:

```
String name = null;
String seat = null;

try
{
  // logic to determine name
  name = ar[0];
  seat = ar[1];
}
catch
{
  e.printStackTrace(); // always put something in the catch
}
```

Then you can refer to the variables outside that block.  Variable scope is inside the block in which the variable is declared; you can use the variable in inner scopes, but not in outer ones.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm :-0